# PHP version Conflict between 5.5 and 7.1 in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, ubuntu

When I want to know my php version by terminal using

```
#php -v
```

I am getting

```
PHP 7.1.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: Apr 11 2017 22:45:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v7.1.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, 
Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

But when I am trying to run info.php written with php code

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

O/P

```
PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21
```

Please let me clear what is happening exactly with my php version.
I installed the full LAMP on my system freshly after un-install APACHE2, PHP & My-Sql.

Comment: maybe this link will help you : https://serverfault.com/a/849863/393598

Answer (score 0):

Also, I recommend check *Loaded Configuration File* item at `phpinfo()` output.

Here I got `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and PHP 7.0.15 with Apache.

Then at the terminal, run `php --ini` and check the same item *Loaded Configuration File:* to see if got any difference.

Comment: Yes As i hv mentioned I got the difference in both of the place